# Point of intersection between two vectors when the direction of one vector is not known

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, artificial-intelligence, game-physics, vectormath

Problem: I have two vectors. I know the starting point of one vector, its direction, its magnitude. I know the starting point of the other vector and its magnitude. I need to find the direction of second vector as well as the position of intersection.

```
   Vector A:                        Vector B:

Position = Known                   Position = Known  
Direction= Known                   Direction= UNKNOWN
Magnitude= Known                   Magnitude= Known

To Find: Point of intersection.
```

Is it possible to find the point of intersection, with the given parameters? If so then how?

**Application: I want to find the position where a player would be found based on the velocity he is moving, and shoot a bullet at him at the moment he would be found, taking into account the time taken for the bullet to reach that virtual target position.**

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1346403

Comment: Isnt the point of intersection known in this question?

Comment: No, I don't believe so. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1346458). 'D' is the unknown collision point. It's actually rather clever, my initial assumption was that you would need to use an iterative solution.

Comment: The question clearly states that the first object moves from known point A to known point B with U1 velocity..only the direction at which the second object should move from known point C needs to be calculated you see..there is only one variable there...I didn't see the  answer but I believe that is solvable by vector algebra...

Comment: I will read the answer now..I think you are onto something..

Comment: Why is the direction of a vector unknown?  Velocity is speed+direction.  Are you trying to account for the player "dodging" i.e., changing direction?  If so, then you have to either "guess"/predict, or "cheat" and change the direction of your bullet if the player's direction changes after firing.

Comment: I am trying to make an AI that shoots at the position player would arrive at...so even though I know where the player is moving...I do not know at which angle the AI should shoot in order for the bullet to hit the player

Comment: Anyway..the link given to me seems interesting, I will try to work it out tomorrow..

Comment: Is the bullet travelling in a straight line or following a parabolic path due to gravity? Btw, your ultimate goal can be solved *without* computing any kind of intersection.

Comment: The path of the bullet is straight..

Comment: And is the player accelerating or moving at a constant speed?

Comment: The player moves at a constant speed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following on from the comments I'm going to take a leap here and answer your ultimate question directly.

Say the player is, at the initial time, at a point `p` and travelling with velocity `v`; your gun is at position `q` and shoots a bullet in *any* direction at speed `s`:

[image]

The length of OP is `vΔt` and that of Q `sΔt`. The angle `a` is given by the dot product:

[image]

We can then use the *cosine rule* to solve for `Δt`:

[image]

Written in this form, we can easily see that it is a quadratic equation, and thus directly solve for `Δt` using the [Quadratic formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula):

[image]

There are a few cases we need to consider here:

- `v < s`: need to take the positive root only as otherwise we would get negative time.
- `v > s` and `dot(PQ, s) < 0`: the bullet will never catch the player.
- `v > s` and `dot(PQ, s) > 0`: take the negative root this time, as the positive root is for a backwards travelling player (longer time; this is also the case presented in the diagram above).

Having the correct value for `Δt` from above will then enable us to find the intersection point `o`, and therefore the intended direction `d`:

[image]

Note that `d` is not normalized. Also, this solution **works for 3D** too, unlike an approach with angles.

Comment: Hello @meowgoesthedog, you solution is good. But I would like to understand a bit more about it. The equation you gave me, can you please break it down further and tell me how you reached there? My math is a bit weak you see. I understood upto the second line...but then when you skipped over to the value of delta t, that is where I lost you...

Answer (score 1):

Let subscript 1 mark the player, and subscript 2 mark the AI:

- initial: position (x_i, y_i)
- angle: alpha_i
- speed: u_i

The positions as a function of time t are :

- player: (x_1 + u_1 * t * cos(alpha_1), y_1 + u_1 * t * sin(alpha_1))
- AI's bullet: (x_2 + u_2 * t * cos(alpha_2), y_2 + u_2 * t * sin(alpha_2))

You have 2 uknowns:

- t - the time of collision
- alpha_2 - the angle the AI should shoot

The collision happens when Xs and Ys match. i.e.:

- x_1 + u_1 * t * cos(alpha_1) = x_2 + u_2 * t * cos(alpha_2)
- y_1 + u_1 * t * sin(alpha_1) = y_2 + u_2 * t * sin(alpha_2)

So,

- alpha_2 = arcos( (x_1 + u_1 * t * cos(alpha_1) - x_2) / u_2 * t )

and also

- alpha_2 = arcsin( (y_1 + u_1 * t * sin(alpha_1) - y_2) / u_1 * t )

substitue your values and equate these to expressions of alpha_2 to obtain t, then you can substitue t in either expression to obtain the angle alpha_2.

Comment: what is arcos and arcsin?

Comment: @Apocaleone arcos=inverse cosine, arcsin=inverse sine

Comment: I am sorry that my math is a bit weak here. I would like to know a couple of things about your answer here.  The alpha_i angle, is it relative to the position of AI with respect to the position of player?

Also, from where did you get the functions of time t that you substituted to the positions of player and AI bullet?

Comment: @Apocaleone the angle is from a reference plane of your choice (has to be the same for both players).

the functions of time for each axis are <initial position> + <speed along axis>*<time>